# hybris make cronjob execute over n hours, then n+1 hours

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How do I achieve this? I mean, I can make it execute every n hours using triggers. But how do I make it execute every n hours, then every n + 1 hours, then repeat this loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can change trigger of cron job with updating job trigger item (Trigger).

Comment: interesting. but then I need to schedule it for update somehow. should I maybe create another cronjob that will be doing this (or that sounds too over the place)?

Comment: Cron job can update it self. Also you can use multiple trigger for same cron job.

Comment: I also think that multiple triggers are a clean solution

Comment: You can achieve this with a single Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single trigger for this. For example "5 3-6/1 * * *" which stands for "At minute 5 past every hour from 3 AM through 6 AM."

Answer (score 0):

After your business logic is done receive the trigger of the cron job set a new activation time and store it via model service.
This will re-schedule the cronjob out-of-the-box.
In you case it could be helping to configure the trigger at a fixed date in the past so the automatic re-scheduling do not happen.